# Can you end Rune Knight's Giants Might at will?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, rune-knight

One of our players is playing a Rune Knight Fighter and has completely hypothetically asked if they could at will end the Giants Might effect from their class features. We cannot find anything that specifies how to end the effect so we are assuming they cannot. Is there any specific rule that would allow this to end at will or are we correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no general rule, so it ends when it says it ends.

There is no general that permits you to end the effect of a class feature at will. So the class feature ends when its description says it ends. In the case of Giant’s Might:

> the following benefits […] last for 1 minute